# Function to calculate Euclidean distance in R

Tags: r, function, euclidean-distance

I am trying to implement KNN classifier in R from scratch on iris data set and as a part of this i have written a function to calculate the Euclidean distance. Here is my code.

```
known_data <- iris[1:15,c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length", "Class")]
unknown_data <- iris[16,c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length")]

# euclidean distance
 euclidean_dist <- function(k,unk) {
 distance <- 0
 for(i in 1:nrow(k))
 distance[i] <- sqrt((k[,1][i] - unk[,1][i])^2 + (k[,2][i] - unk[,2][i])^2)
 return(distance)
} 

euclidean_dist(known_data, unknown_data)
```

However, when i call the function it's returning the first value correctly and rest as NA. 
Could anyone show where i could have gone wrong with the code? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `unknown_data` has one row, however, in your function, you try to access the 2nd, 3rd etc. rows of it via `unk[,1][i]` which will be `NA`.

Comment: @hodgenovice Thanks for pointing this out to me. I fixed the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aim is to calculate the distance between the ith row of known_data, and the single unknown_data point.

**How to fix your code**

When you calculate `distance[i]`, you're trying to access the ith row of the unknown data point, which doesn't exits, and is hence `NA`. I believe your code should run fine if you make the following edits:

```
known_data <- iris[1:15,c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length", "Class")] 
unknown_data <- iris[16,c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length")]

# euclidean distance
euclidean_dist <- function(k,unk) {
  # Make distance a vector [although not technically required]
  distance <- rep(0, nrow(k))

  for(i in 1:nrow(k))
    # Change unk[,1][i] to unk[1,1] and similarly for unk[,2][i]
    distance[i] <- sqrt((k[,1][i] - unk[1,1])^2 + (k[,2][i] - unk[1,2])^2)

  return(distance)
} 

euclidean_dist(known_data, unknown_data)
```

One final note - in the version of R I'm using, the known dataset uses a `Species` as opposed to `Class` column

**An alternative method**

As suggested by @Roman Luštrik, the entire aim of getting the Euclidean distances can be achieved with a simple one-liner:

```
sqrt((known_data[, 1] - unknown_data[, 1])^2 + (known_data[, 2] - unknown_data[, 2])^2)
```

This is very similar to the function you wrote, but does it in vectorised form, rather than through a loop, which is often a preferable way of doing things in R.

Comment: Or just `sqrt((known_data[, 1] - unknown_data[, 1])^2 + (known_data[, 2] - unknown_data[, 2])^2)`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Yes, excellent suggestion - I think that's nicer way of calculating it, and have included this suggestion in the answer, but kept the code fix as that's main thing which was actually asked.

Answer (score 0):

The best and fastst way is using h2o package:

```
#load library
    library(h2o)
#initialize the node
    h2o.init()
#transform the df to h2o type
    known_data<-as.h2o(known_data)
    unknown_data<-as.h2o(unknown_data)
#create a matrix in which the distances are going to be record
    matrix1<-h2o.createFrame(rows=nrow(known_data),cols=unknown_data)
#do a loop to calculate the distance between all the rows of both df
    for(i in 1:nrow(unknown_data)){
    matrix[,i]<-as.data.frame(h2o.distance(known_data, unknown_data[i,],"l2"))
    }
```