# Euclidean Distances between rows of two data frames in R

Tags: r, apply, euclidean-distance

Calculating Euclidean Distances in **R** is easy. A good example can be found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780199/function-to-calculate-euclidean-distance-in-r). The vectorised form is:

```
sqrt((known_data[, 1] - unknown_data[, 1])^2 + (known_data[, 2] - unknown_data[, 2])^2)
```

What would be the fastest, most efficient way to get Euclidean Distances for each row of one data frame with all rows of another data frame? A particular function from `apply()` family?  Thanks!

Comment: I assume that both data frame need to have the same variables? Because otherwise you cannot compute a Euclidean distance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try `outer` + `dist` like below

```
outer(
  1:nrow(known_data),
  1:nrow(unknown_data),
  FUN = Vectorize(function(x,y) dist(rbind(known_data[x,],unknown_data[y,])))
)
```

Comment: I was seconds off posting an almost identical answer! Won't bother now... +1

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `dist()` function (which is very efficient) on the combination of the two data frames and then remove the unneeded distances, if you like. Example:

```
df1 <- iris[1:5, -5]
df2 <- iris[6:10, -5]

all_distances <- dist(rbind(df1, df2))
all_distances <- as.matrix(all_distances)

# remove unneeded distances
all_distances[1:5, 1:5] <- NA
all_distances[6:10, 6:10] <- NA
```

Comment: Great approach for smallish data, but on large data (especially if one data frame is very large) this is a lot of wasted computation.

Comment: Agree! My data is unfortunately big which is why I have asked about some `apply()`-like solution.

Comment: Well, I don't think that any other option will provide a solution to the asymptotic computational effort, which is also very high when only computing the distances from the different data frames. If your data is so large, computing any distance matrix will be challenging.